# Converting elements of 2d-array

Tags: ruby, arrays, type-conversion

I have the following 3x3 array:

```
grid = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]
```

I want to convert each number from a String to a Fixnum. I tried:

```
grid.each{ |thing| thing.each { |subthing| subthing = subthing.to_i }}
```

However, `puts grid[0][0].class` still outputs `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each` just iterates over each value, it doesn't change the contents. Try using `map`.

```
foo = grid.map{ |a| a.map(&:to_i) }  # foo => [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], but grid is still the original
```

If you want to update grid in place:

```
grid.each { |a| a.map!(&:to_i) }
```

Comment: Slightly more efficient: `grid.each { |a| a.map!(&:to_i) }`. No need need to make new inner arrays, just replace their elements in place with [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21).